# How to know what kernel was running in a certain Ubuntu distribution

Tags: kernel

I have a problem with alsa/jack and the kernel (I suppose). Since everything was working well when I installed the Ubuntu from fresh on mid-December, I was wondering how can I retrieve the information on what kernel that version was using by default.

Comment: `uname -r` will displays the version running; but if this wasn't the grub default; it won't know/tell you that, just what is currently running.

Comment: Look under the "advanced" Grub options, and see which old kernels are listed.  You can still select and run those.

Comment: Hi @ubfan1. Unfortunately, I had to change computer, so I don't have any previous kernel history

Comment: You haven't provided a OS/release or any useful information to know; the release details provide the biggest clue (esp. for non-LTS releases), or for LTS release you also need to know the ISO used to install the system, as original & .1 default to the GA kernel, .2 and later default to HWE kernels thus change for each subsequent point release. Release information on what you were running is you're best bet; fresh mid-Dec 2018 install is a clue, but doesn't tell us what release you were using (19.10? 18.04/18.04.1 with GA kernel, 18.04.2/18.04.3 installation with HWE defaulted).  Release was?

Comment: Hi @guiverc. You are very right. In mid-December 2019 I downloaded an Ubuntu 19.10 release. Do not know much more. It was from this website: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for, but with 19.10 there is no GA/HWE kernel choices (applies only to LTS (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) where for example 18.04 can use it's original GA 4.15 kernel, or the rolling HWE kernel (currently 5.3 or identical to your 19.10 system; ie. HWE allows 18.04 to use 18.10's, then 19.04's, then 19.10's and will eventually settle on 20.04's when 18.04.5 is released in August-2020).   My first comment contains the command to tell you what is actually running; you can view /boot/ for details on what options are installed...